# ReactJS: Save button value on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a form, and I have two submit button. Now i'm trying to save the value from the button to make two different api call based precisely on the value of the button.

My problem is that sometimes the value from the button results "undefined" so when it is clicked nothing happend.

```
 return (
              <AvForm model={{}} onSubmit={saveEntity}>
    //.....
    <Button id="pdf" replace color="info" data-cy="entityCreatePDF" type="submit" onClick={buttonClicked} value="pdf">
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="save" />
                      &nbsp;
                      <span className="d-none d-md-inline"> PDF </span>
                    </Button>
                    &nbsp;
                    <Button color="primary" id="csv" data-cy="entityCreateCSV" type="submit" onClick={buttonClicked} value="csv">
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="save" />
                      &nbsp;<span className="d-none d-md-inline"> CSV </span>
                    </Button>
    
    )

  const buttonClicked = event => {
    console.log('event target', event.target.value);
    setButtonClick(event.target.value);
  };

  const saveEntity = (event, errors, values) => {
//....
 filteredEntities(params, sorting)
}


const filteredEntities = (params, sort) => {
    console.log('-- buttonClick --', buttonClick);
// there sometimes I receive undefined and so it doesn't enter in the if
    if (buttonClick === 'pdf') {
      getReportPDF(params, sort);
    }
    if (buttonClick === 'csv') {
      getReportCSV(params, sort);
    }
}
```

There is something that I should doing to avoid this behavior (i.e. that the key results in an undefined value and therefore does not allow me to take any action?).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

Replace

```
  const buttonClicked = event => {
    console.log('event target', event.target.value);
    setButtonClick(event.target.value);
  };
```

with

```
  const buttonClicked = event => {
    console.log('event target', event.currentTarget.value);
    setButtonClick(event.currentTarget.value);
  };
```

Why?
Sometimes you click the button itself, sometimes e.g. icon inside it - the element you click is actually a "target". "currentTarget" however allows the use of element the event listener was assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be arising from setState being asynchronous, ie, the state doesn't change immediately after `setButtonClick` is called. You can use a ref to sidestep this issue, if you don't need to re-render when `buttonClick` is changed, and use `buttonClick.current` to get the value.

```
const buttonClick = useRef();
...

const buttonClicked = event => {
    console.log('event target', event.target.value);
    buttonClick.current = event.target.value;
  };
...

const filteredEntities = (params, sort) => {
    console.log('-- buttonClick --', buttonClick.current);
    if (buttonClick.current === 'pdf') {
      getReportPDF(params, sort);
    }
    if (buttonClick.current === 'csv') {
      getReportCSV(params, sort);
    }
}
```

If you need to re-render when it changes, use both the state and a ref.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly save the value to the state. As it is not an input field, no need to deal with `event.target.value`

```
.....
<Button onClick={() => setButtonClick('csv')}
<Button onClick={() => setButtonClick('pdf')}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this has the exact same functionality as the function in the question.